# Is there a way to automatically dim the display on/off based on the movement of the cursor?

Tags: windows, laptop, display, multiple-monitors

I have an Acer Predator notebook, which recently started to present a common issue with its screen (it keeps flickering all the time). The problem is that using it like this is very irritating, as it distracts me. Since I need an auxiliary screen for the work I do, I can't do without an extra display to extend the open programs. For a few days, I disabled the laptop screen and used everything only on the external display, but it's practically impossible to continue this way. Then, an idea came to mind: 'I'll manually disable and enable the faulty screen using the function key whenever I want to see the programs', but that's not very practical either, as it becomes quite laborious.

I researched and even found something similar to what I wanted in an old forum thread, recommending a software called 'Multiscreen Blank', but still, despite making it a bit easier, it is not configurable for what I'm looking for (to automate the activation/deactivation of the screen). Does anyone here know of any other program that performs the exact function I'm looking for? To recap: dim the screen from 0 to 100% when the mouse cursor hovers over the screen, and back to 0 when it leaves. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://superuser.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)
Software recommendations are off-topic, but you could try [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)